# Is it recommended to pass a view model to View method but catch the passed object with an entity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Assume that I have an entity `Person` with `DoB` (date of birth), `Name`, `BloodType`, etc.

I want to use a view model `PersonViewModel` that consists of `Name`, `BloodType`, etc, excluding the `DoB`. I pass `PersonViewModel` to the `View` method but I catch the passed object via `@model` of type `Person`.

Is it recommended to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, if you pass PersonViewModel's object you will catch view model's object, and also it isn't recommended.
you can use AutoMapper to map your models to view models and vice versa